# Определение размера папки средствами php

Tags: php, sendmail

Подскажите, пожалуйста! Как реализовать определение размеров папки с помощью php.
Есть файлообменник, с помощью него народ загружает файлы на сервер. Я хочу, чтобы при отправке файла на сервер запускался скрипт, который определяет размер папки куда все падает, и если суммарный размер превысил 1Гб, то происходит отправка письма мне на почту.

Answer (score 7):

```
function getFilesSize($path)
{
    $fileSize = 0;
    $dir = scandir($path);

    foreach($dir as $file)
    {
        if (($file!='.') && ($file!='..'))
            if(is_dir($path . '/' . $file))
                $fileSize += getFilesSize($path.'/'.$file);
            else
                $fileSize += filesize($path . '/' . $file);
    }

    return $fileSize;
}
```

[источник](http://gloomm.blogspot.com/2008/04/php.html)

Answer (score 5):

Через [SPL](http://php.net/spl) немного попроще.

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/path/to/dir", FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)
);

$size = 0;
foreach ($it as $fi) { 
    $size += $fi->getSize();
}
echo $size;
```

Answer (score 1):

Если много подпапок, их вес может повлиять на общий объем.
Я сделал вот так:

```
public function getDirectorySize(string $folderPath): int
{
  $files = scandir($folderPath);
  unset($files[0], $files[1]);
  $size = 0;
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (file_exists($folderPath . '/' . $file)) {
      $size += filesize($folderPath . '/' . $file);
      if (is_dir($folderPath . '/' . $file)) {
        $size += $this->getDirectorySize($folderPath . '/' . $file);
      }
    }

  }

  return $size;
}
```

Про быстродействие сказать нечего, 10МБ за 3 секунды, лол, но у меня достаточно глубокая вложенность